# Serialize a Scrapy Item for XML output

Tags: python, xml, scrapy, xml-serialization

I am new to scrapy and I am looking for a way to serialize my Scrapy Item in order to be able to add attributes to my XML output, for it to look this way :

```
<field name='example'> i have some data scraped here </field>
```

I'm trying to find a way of adding the "name" attribute, for example. I know it may be possible by overriding the export_item() method within XmlItemExporter class, but I've had no luck so far. So far my XmlExportPipeline looks like this :

```
from scrapy.exporters import XmlItemExporter

class XmlExportPipeline(object):

def open_spider(self, spider):
    self.file = open('%s_products.xml' % spider.name, 'w+b')
    self.exporter = XmlItemExporter(self.file, item_element='field', root_element='items')
    self.exporter.start_exporting()

def close_spider(self, spider):
    self.exporter.finish_exporting()
    self.file.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
    return item
```

Also, so far, all of my data is a different Field of my Item, but ideally I would have some of those fields as attributes of other fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change the `XMLItemExporter` and create your custom one. Create `exporters.py` in your project and add below code

```
import six
from scrapy.exporters import XmlItemExporter
from scrapy.utils.python import is_listlike

class MyXmlExportPipeline(XmlItemExporter):
    def _export_xml_field(self, name, serialized_value, depth):
        self._beautify_indent(depth=depth)
        self.xg.startElement("field", {"name": name})
        if hasattr(serialized_value, 'items'):
            self._beautify_newline()
            for subname, value in serialized_value.items():
                self._export_xml_field(subname, value, depth=depth+1)
            self._beautify_indent(depth=depth)
        elif is_listlike(serialized_value):
            self._beautify_newline()
            for value in serialized_value:
                self._export_xml_field('value', value, depth=depth+1)
            self._beautify_indent(depth=depth)
        elif isinstance(serialized_value, six.text_type):
            self._xg_characters(serialized_value)
        else:
            self._xg_characters(str(serialized_value))
        self.xg.endElement("field")
        self._beautify_newline()
```

The only two changes that I did were change

```
self.xg.startElement(name, {})
....
self.xg.endElement(name)
```

From original export to

```
self.xg.startElement("field", {"name" :name})
....
self.xg.endElement("field")
```

Then update your `settings.py` and add

```
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'xml': 'so.exporters.MyXmlExportPipeline'
}
```

Then I created a simple scraper to test the output

```
class XMLExport(Spider):
    name = "xml"

    start_urls = ["http://www.tarunlalwani.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        yield {"first_name": "tarun", "last_name": "lalwani"}

    pass
```

And test it using `scrapy crawl xml -o test.xml` and the output XML file was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
<item><field name="first_name">tarun</field><field name="last_name">lalwani</field></item>
</items>
```